# a href is not working on bootstrap 3.0

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to convert following into bootstrap 3.0. Some how  is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input type=text class="form-control" name=m_id value="{m_id}" maxlength=16 required fld_esssential option=regId label="ID" placeholder="ID>

<input type=hidden name=chk_id required fld_esssential label="id-doublecheck">

<a href="javascript:chkId()" class="btn btn-primary">ID check</a>
```

Comment: What happens or does not happen? Have you checked for error messages?

Comment: As a first step, please close the " for the first input placeholder attribute. <input type=text class="form-control" name=m_id value="{m_id}" maxlength=16 required fld_esssential option=regId label="ID" placeholder="ID">. Once you do this. you should be able to hit the javascript function chkId() if it is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your first line you have an unclosed quote.

```
placeholder="ID
```

so it's asigning everything until the quote is closed:

```
placeholder= "ID> <input type=hidden name=chk_id required fld_esssential label="
```

Comment: @user3796291 You're welcome! if it solved the problem consider to mark my answer as accepted clicking on the check mark. Instructions [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Change your first input to close the quotes for placeholder attribute. Here is the updated one:

```
<input type=text class="form-control" name=m_id value="{m_id}" maxlength=16 required fld_esssential option=regId label="ID" placeholder="ID">

<input type=hidden name=chk_id required fld_esssential label="id-doublecheck">

<a href="javascript:chkId()" class="btn btn-primary">ID check</a>
```

Define the function chkId() and you are good to go.

```
function chkId()
{ alert('it works');}
```